# I am installing requirement.txt getting the error EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\envs\requirements.txt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am installing a requirements.txt in Visual studio code for windows. I type in the terminal in visual studio code conda activate py310. Everything works fine. Then I type conda install -n requirements.txt and get the error EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\envs\requirements.txt

How do I fix this? Thanks

I even created the environment variables a long time ago. Here are the env variables and yes I reset my pc a long time when creating the environment variables. Also the env variables are the correct path as far as I know .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNMAr.jpg

Here is what happens when I type conda info

```
  active environment : py310
    active env location : C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\envs\py310
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\nmyle\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\nmyle\.condarc
          conda version : 22.9.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.9
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.5=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\nmyle\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\nmyle\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.12 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22000
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I think there must be something wrong with C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\envs\requirements.txt I just don't know what. I tried searching forC:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3\envs\requirements.txt but I can't find anythin on my pc.

[Here is where my requirements.txt is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3il5.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem with vscode. Where is your requirements.txt?

Comment: Thanks I screwed up the folder system I fixed it now dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo. The `--name,-n` argument is string to name the resulting environment, whereas the `--file` argument is a `requirements.txt` file. So, instead want something like

```bash
conda create -n foo --file requirements.txt
```

where `"foo"` would be the name of the new environment.